# Multiplying array elements by n, and storing them in a new array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have an array, in this case double [] v, which will take 4 values (0, 1, 2, 3).

I need to multiply each element of the array by "c" and store the result of each one back in a new array. I have tried it but i always end up getting the error message that double cannot be converted to double []. I can't figure out why and the examples here in SO have not helped.

```
public class q7_2014 {
    public static double [] multiply ( double [] v, double c){
        double [] newArray = new double [4];
        double multiply = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
            multiply = v[i]*c;



            System.out.println(multiply);

        }



        return newArray;

    }

}
```

The code works fine and prints what is supposed to go into the array, but I just can't figure out how.

what am I missing? (the print statement was just to check if the code was working as expected in terms of results).
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, since i'm not asking how to initialize an array since you can see in my code that I do that on the second line. I'm simply asking how to store the multiplication of each element of one array into another one. Thank you anway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the results of your multiplication in `newArray`. Also, you should size `newArray` by the passed in array `v` length. Like,

```
public static double[] multiply(double[] v, double c) {
    double[] newArray = new double[v.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = v[i] * c;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

And in Java 8+, you could produce the same result with a single line of code using a `DoubleStream` and a `map` operation. Like,

```
public static double[] multiply(double[] v, double c) {
    return DoubleStream.of(v).map(d -> d * c).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact i was just missing newArray "[i]" . Im sure your single line of code would also work, but since im still new to Java i'm not familiar with this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the result of the multiplication back into `newArray`

```
public class q7_2014 {
    public static double [] multiply (double[] v, double c){
        double[] newArray = new double[v.length];
        // You don't need multiply since
        // you need to return newArray
        //double multiply = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
            newArray[i] = v[i] * c;
            // uncomment if you need to print the current value
            // System.out.println(newArray[i]);
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to give a reason why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public class q7_2014 {
public static double [] multiply ( double [] v, double c){
    double [] newArray = new double [4];
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
        newArray[i] = v[i]*c;
        }

    return newArray;
   }
}
```